# Why does Type.GetType not return a Type when given an input the exact same as typof(X).GetFullName?

Tags: c#, .net, types, typeof, gettype

Let's say I have a project containing a large collection of subclasses and I want to interrogate them on the fly.

Given a full namespace and class name:

```cs
    SomeCompany.SomeProduct.Data.Sample.Client.clsName
```

In my test class I have the following:

```cs
    string fullClassName = typeof(SomeCompany.SomeProduct.Data.Sample.Client.clsName).FullName;
    // returns "SomeCompany.SomeProduct.Data.Sample.Client.clsName"

    Type classType = Type.GetType("SomeCompany.SomeProduct.Data.Sample.Client.clsName");
    // throws an error or with false for error reporting returns null
```

How can thew same exact classnames not work? What am I missing? I'm not shortening anything with using so the full entire classname is being used and not working in both cases even though they should rationally be identical.

Comment: I created a namespace named `Test` with a class named `Program`, and neither of these throw an exception: `var x = Type.GetType("Test.Program"); var y = Type.GetType(typeof(Test.Program).FullName);`. Please post a reproducible sample.

Comment: @RufusL I'm looking at an image of it right now...

`Type testType = typeof(SomeCompany.SomeProduct.Data.Sample.Client.clsName);
Type testTypeResult = testTypeName = Type.GetType(testType.FullName);`

testType is being populated.

Comment: @shahkalpesh This was exactly the issue, thank you. Want to answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: @JayCroghan: Go ahead to upvote the original question. I am not adding anything new here. In general, see if your question is already answered before posting afresh. Cheers.